# Understanding the notation of a book when derivating

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

I'm trying to understand the notation that the book  uses.

The book says

$(1)$ $y=a\cdot \sin x$
and then the derivate of $(1)$ is
$(2)$ $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-a \cdot \sin x$

I don't get what to do when derivating to get $(2)$, and what  exactly $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ means.

Comment: I think *senx* is meant to be $\sin x$.  Do you mean that you don't understand derivatives?  If not, it's usually a month or so in a calculus class to get derivatives.  SOrry if I am misunderstanding.

Comment: The symbol $\dfrac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}$ denotes the second derivative of $y$, often denoted by $y''$.

Comment: You can also think of $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$ as $\frac d{dx} \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)$.

Comment: Yes I know how to derivate, but in class we use the y′′ as Git Gud says ,and nevermind that the book when say derivate , it was referring to derivate two times.
also @legâteauaufromage thanks for your clarification,it was helpfull.
Really aprecciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first derivative of $y=a \cdot \sin x$ is:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=a \cdot \cos x$$

The second derivative of $y=a \cdot \sin x$,which is also the first derivative of $\frac{dy}{dx}=a \cdot \cos x$,is:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-a \cdot \sin x$$